# Want to make sense of array dimensions in logistic regression algorithms

Tags: logistic, python, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement a simple logistic regression algorithm from scratch in python (for learning purposes). Every article I've seen online so far presents the following expression for $z$ (argument of the sigmoid function):

$$z = \theta^T\cdot x$$

However when they implement it in code they always use `np.dot(X, theta)` which is not the same thing. I have carefully tried to trace the dimensions of all the arrays as follows:

Dot product property: $\theta^T\cdot x = x^T\cdot\theta$

- $x$ is of dimension $l\times (d+1)$ where $l$ is the number of records and $d+1$ the number of features (including the $x_0$ ones vector).
- $\theta$ is of dimensions $1 \times (d+1)$ (every column in $x$ gets a weight, including the ones vector).
- $z$ is the dot product of $\theta^T$ and $x$, it will have dimensions $((d+1)\times 1)\cdot(l \times 1) =  ??$ --> **DOES NOT WORK**!

There appears to be no way to arrange the last statement such that it remains mathematically correct and yielding an array of dimension $l\times1$ or $1\times l$ without fundamentally changing either:

- the shape of $x$
- the equation itself (as they do in the code)

So which is correct? The code or the mathematical statement? Why are they contradictory? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few options here:

1. the code raises an exception because the shape is wrong;
2. the code is *semantically* wrong and computes the wrong value but does not raise an exception;
3. the code works correctly and the text simply mis-states the shape (equivalently, the code implements a different shape than stated in the text);
4. both the text and the code are wrong.

We know that logistic regression is just a transformation of a linear model. Therefore, we know that a linear combination of the features is correct. This implies that the code is correct given specific shapes for inputs, and also that the text is correct given a *different* specific shapes for inputs. Therefore, we can exclude (4).

That leaves explanations (1), (2) or (3). I can't validate whether the code works correctly based on the content of the original post.

If I had to place a bet, my money would be on option (3): the author wrote the code and the text separately, and never bothered to check whether the description matched the code. As you point out, one can rewrite a matrix-vector product using transposes -- it seems that the authors did so but their notation is sloppy.